# How to handle 'is this mentioned in any scripture' questions?

Tags: discussion

There are many questions which ask scriptural refrence of something. Now, if that's found in some scripture then, it can be answered saying it's mentioned in so and so scripture(s).

But, answer like 'it's not mentioned in any scripture' is almost impossible as there are no fixed number of scriptures and such questions would cause worst case seach scenario and would remain unanswered for long time.

How we should handle them? Should we close such questions as 'Needs more focus' and ask users to limit the question to particular set of scriptures. So that the question can be answered like it's not mentioned in so and so versions of that set of scriptures. Or, should we use wiki like answer where one user can write like it's not mentioned in a,b,c scriptures and another user can write it's not mentioned in x,y,z scriptures and so on. Or, in some other way?